# Unresolved Reference using Kotlin for android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting Unresolved Reference when compiling

Error:(42, 26) Unresolved reference: r1
Error:(42, 36) Unresolved reference: ds

in the onClick method variables r1, and ds are shown to be in errors.
in kotlin all varibales are final. so how come it is not accepting it. 
please advice following is the script

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val b1: Button = findViewById(R.id.add)

        val a1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.opr1)
        val a2: EditText = findViewById(R.id.opr2)

        val d1: Int = (a1.getText().toString().toInt())
        val d2: Int = (a2.getText().toString().toInt())

      var r1: TextView = findViewById(R.id.res)
        var ds :Int =d1+d2


    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        when (v?.id) {

            R.id.add ->  r1.text= (ds).toString()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As to your next question: Are you sure you want to compute `d1 + d2` only once at the beginning? You should probably move reading current values to the click listener. (Do what CrazyApple says.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ds` is local variable that can only be accessed within the function `onCreate()`. If you want to sum up the numbers of the `EditText`, you should put your addition logic inside the `onClick()` method:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.add -> {
            val d1: Int = et1.text.toString().toInt()
            val d2: Int = et2.text.toString().toInt()
            val ds = d1 + d2
            r1.text = ds.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should declare `r1` and other view reference as class member so that they can be accessed within your `Activity` class but not only `onCreate()`.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that `v` is never null.

Comment: what you are suggesting is correct, but some times we want same variable in the main and in the methods so this will create a confilct it is better to define it outside the on create as suggested by eugen pechanec ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

`r1` is a local variable in `onCreate` so it's not accessible outside of this function.

Declare it outside of the function like so:

```
private lateinit var r1: TextView
```

Assign it in `onCreate` like so:

```
r1 = findViewById(R.id.res)
```

Then you can access it as you expect:

```
r1.text= ds.toString()
```

The same rule applies for other variables you want to access outside of `onCreate`.

#### Why lateinit

`onCreate` is not a constructor so `r1` is uninitialized before that. But you know that `onCreate` is the first thing called in the activity lifecycle so when you initialize the variable here it will always be non-null.

Otherwise you'd have to declare the variable like this:

```
private var r1: TextView?
```

and access it with the `!!` operator, for example:

```
r1!!.setText(...)
```

Comment: Unrelated: While at it, please, give your variables more meaningful names. When you look at the code in a few weeks you're going to ask yourself "What the hell does `r1` mean?".

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation.i did forgot to declare it outside the oncreate. you are right the variable names should be easy to understand i will definitely follow it from the next tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The variable **ds** only exists into the first function. You must declare it outside to access it from the second.

Comment: yes sir u r right , i missed this point. thank you for the reply